# std::atomic<bool> fetch_and() and fetch_or() realization

Tags: c++, c++11, msvcrt, std, stdatomic

C++11 doc defines `std::atomic::fetch_or()` and `std::atomic::fetch_and()` only for Integral types. In this way, MSVC++ 2012 `std::atomic<bool>` is not implements this functions. Does anyone know why?

I found only this solution. Implement specialization for `std::atomic_fetch_or<bool>` and `std::atomic_fetch_or<and>`.

```
namespace std
{
    template<>
    inline bool atomic_fetch_or<bool>(std::atomic<bool>* atom, bool val)
    {
        bool bRes = !val;
        atom->compare_exchange_strong(bRes, true);
        return bRes;
    }

    template<>
    inline bool atomic_fetch_or_explicit<bool>(std::atomic<bool>* atom,
        bool val, std::memory_order order)
    {
        bool bRes = !val;
        atom->compare_exchange_strong(bRes, true, order);
        return bRes;
    }


    template<>
    inline bool atomic_fetch_and<bool>(std::atomic<bool>* atom, bool val)
    {
        bool bRes = true;
        atom->compare_exchange_strong(bRes, val);
        return bRes;
    }

    template<>
    inline bool atomic_fetch_and_explicit<bool>(std::atomic<bool>* atom,
        bool val, std::memory_order order)
    {
        bool bRes = true;
        atom->compare_exchange_strong(bRes, val, order);
        return bRes;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately it is inconvenient to use as if it were a built-in operators.

Comment: `bool` is an integral type... I would venture that MSVC has some bug...

Comment: @Massa The standard doesn't say `atomic_fetch_and` (and similar functions) is available for `atomic<T>` where `T` is any integral type. It explicitly lists the types for which it's available, in **29.5 Table 146** and **29.6.5 Table 147**. `atomic<bool>` is *not* so listed.